# file list not updated on DAGs

Tags: python, airflow

I followed this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SYOUbiGtGiU

And successfully installed airflow. The problem is that I have a mount directory in E:\dag And I add files to it. [image]

I use airflow initdb and it successfully compiles my file. The problem is it doesnt show on portal:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't have the scheduler running, so the DAG is not picked up and the DAG list may not update (as the warning on the top of the webserver admin page says).

You should try to open another terminal and run the command:

```
airflow scheduler
```

(And then wait a bit and refresh a couple of times the webserver admin page until you see the DAG appearing)